# Laravel 5 - weird sessions

Tags: laravel, session

in my application, after few requests, Laravel sessions randomly expired.

On my site, i had invalid links to images, i repaired them and everything works fine now.

What could be the problem? How could repairing links helped Laravel sessions from not being randomly deleted?

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: Your question gives details that are very broad. If there's a problem with session it would make sense for you to include the Laravel session configuration file, if you think it had something to do with invalid links (although I can't see how) then you should explain what was wrong and perhaps include the relevant code that you fixed. Putting more effort into making your questions as complete as possible will yield you faster answers.

Answer (score 1):

All your routes are inside middleware 'web' ? If you redirect to a route outside 'web' you loose sessions. Check that and return please.